# Using Laravel, SMTP Mail not Working in Live Server

Tags: php, email, laravel, deployment, smtp

My configuration works fine on Localhost. The email go through successful. But when I deploy it on the live server Laravel gives me the following error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

in my laravel/app/config/mail.php

```
<?php

return array(

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
|
*/

'driver' => 'smtp',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
| 
*/

'port' => 587,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => array('address' => 'username@gmail.com', 'name' => 'vanvlymen'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => 'tls',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => 'username@gmail.com',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Password
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
| messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
| connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
|
*/

'password' => 'your real password',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail "Pretend"
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
| web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
| you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
|
*/

'pretend' => false,

 );
```

in my routes.php

```
 Route::get('/', "HomeController@showWelcome");

 Route::post('/','HomeController@contactus');

 Route::get('portfolio', "HomeController@showPortfolio");

 Route::get('education', "HomeController@showEducation");

 Route::get('blog', "HomeController@showBlog");
```

What is going on? Can you please help me, Thanks.

Comment: What does the error.log says ?

Comment: the message was "Whoops, looks like something went wrong". Where can I find error.log?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have used encryption as **ssl** and drive as **sendmail** for live.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following things.

> This is my mail working mail configuration.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST= smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=demo@gmail.com // email id that working and capable to send mails
MAIL_PASSWORD=test123 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Generate key properly

```
"php artisan key:generate"
```

> If your get "OpenSSL extension is required" error,

```
enable the openssl extension by opening php.ini.
```

> permissions to .env

```
sudo chown -R www-data pathto/.env
```