# Why does Laravel mail not work on a live server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a hosting on Godaddy. I have written an email app. It works properly on localhost. I can't run on hosting. When you enter the smtp settings of different servers, it still does not work. I also read the following topics.

[Why mail laravel not working on the staging server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525731/why-mail-laravel-not-working-on-the-staging-server)

[Using Laravel, SMTP Mail not Working in Live Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075262/using-laravel-smtp-mail-not-working-in-live-server)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-sending-mail-not-working-on-production-server

[Connection could not be established with host mailtrap.io [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. #0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690219/connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-mailtrap-io-php-network-getaddres)

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=user@domain.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Settings running on my localhost.

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.domain.org [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0]
```

Godaddy smtp settings when I give 500 error. It does not generate any error.log

Also

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
```

and

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

I tried them by looking at other links. but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: The solution could be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666172/laravel-5-5-mail-not-working-with-mail-driver#47685775).

Comment: Are you on shared hosting?  Or do you have a VPS or dedicated server?

Comment: Have a shared hosting

Comment: Are you trying to send with the localhost or a 3rd party service?

Comment: yes I'm sending through my other server. but the same settings do not work on this hosting.

Comment: You may not be able to use an external mail server with shared hosting.  https://www.godaddy.com/help/send-form-mail-using-an-smtp-relay-server-953

Comment: godaddy settings don't work either.

Comment: I will post the localhost settings below that worked for an old app.  Be aware that messages may take up to 5 minutes to go through using their relay.

Comment: Please check this out also https://stackoverflow.com/a/57847333/4650866

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you may not be able to use an external mail relay with shared hosting. 
https://www.godaddy.com/help/send-form-mail-using-an-smtp-relay-server-953

These should be the GoDaddy localhost settings:

```php
### MAIL SERVER
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=user@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Your Company"
```

Comment: By default, encryption comes from tls. Null did.